# Error con RawQuery en SQLite

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sqlite

Buenas amigos, hice mi base de datos para hacer el registro de usuarios y su login, usé clases separadas para la base:

```
public class Usuario {
    private int id;
    private String nombre;
    private String password;

    public Usuario(int id, String nombre, String password) {
        this.id = id;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

Esta es mi segunda clase

```
public class Utilidades {

    //Constantes campos tabla usuario
    public static final String TABLA_USUARIO = "usuario";
    public static final String ID = "id";
    public static final String NOMBRE = "nombre";
    public static final String PASS = "password";

    public static final String CREAR_TABLA_USUARIO="create table " + TABLA_USUARIO+ "("+ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + NOMBRE + "TEXT, " + PASS + "TEXT)";

}
```

Sin embargo al momento de realizar la verificación de los usuarios en la activity correspondiente me sale un error donde el rawQuery está vacio.
Esto es lo que tengo en mi clase donde hago el inicio de sesión

```
public class loggeo extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText et1,et2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_03_loggeo);

        ConexionSQLiteHelper conn = new ConexionSQLiteHelper(this,"bd_usuarios",null,1);

        et1= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtUsrLog);
        et2= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPassLog);
    }

    public void onClick (View view){
        iniciarSesion();
    }

    public void iniciarSesion(){
        Cursor fila;


        ConexionSQLiteHelper conn = new ConexionSQLiteHelper(this,"bd_usuarios",null,1);

        SQLiteDatabase db = conn.getWritableDatabase();

        String usr=et1.getText().toString();
        String pass=et2.getText().toString();

        fila=db.rawQuery("select "+ Utilidades.NOMBRE+", "+Utilidades.PASS+"from "+Utilidades.TABLA_USUARIO+" where "+Utilidades.NOMBRE+"='"+usr+"' and "+Utilidades.PASS+"='"+pass+"'",null);

        if (fila.moveToFirst()){
            String filUs=fila.getString(0);
            String filPass=fila.getString(1);

            if (et1.equals(filUs)&&filPass.equals(pass)){
                Intent ven=new Intent(this,drawer_perfil.class);
                startActivity(ven);
                et1.setText("");
                et2.setText("");
            }
        }
        db.close();

    }
}
```

Me gustaría que me pudieran orientar en donde está mi error ya que no logro comprenderlo realmente, espero puedan ayudarme.

Edito: Clase donde realizo el registro de usuarios

```
public class registroUsuario extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText nombre,password;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_02_registro);

        ConexionSQLiteHelper conn = new ConexionSQLiteHelper(this,"bd_usuarios",null,1);

        nombre = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtUsuarioNuevo);
        password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtPassNuevo);

    }
    public void onClick (View view){
        registrarUsuarios();
    }

    private void registrarUsuarios() {
        ConexionSQLiteHelper conn = new ConexionSQLiteHelper(this,"bd_usuarios",null,1);

        SQLiteDatabase db = conn.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(Utilidades.NOMBRE,nombre.getText().toString());
        values.put(Utilidades.PASS,password.getText().toString());

        Long enviado = db.insert(Utilidades.TABLA_USUARIO,Utilidades.ID,values);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Registro satisfactorio",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        db.close();

        Intent siguiente = new Intent(registroUsuario.this, loggeo.class);
        startActivity(siguiente);

    }
}
```

Comment: Cuál es el error que marca? Donde rellenas `Utilidades.NOMBRE`?

Comment: Está marcando mi Cursor como nulo y se llena en mi clase de registro, la anexaré en la pregunta

Comment: Noto que no estas dando espacios a los SQL. Por ejemplo cuando creas la tabla tienes esto: `NOMBRE + "TEXT,` que si lo compilamos mentalmente daria esto: `NOMBRETEXT` y deberia de ser `NOMBRE TEXT`, separado por un espacio. Comentes el mismo error por todo el codigo. Dale espacio a todo el sql lo requiera e intenta de nuevo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error se debe a que tu Query es incorrecto, estas omitiendo algunos espacios, eso provoca que la consulta retorne un Cursor con valor null, tu consulta es incorrecta:

```
fila=db.rawQuery("select "+ Utilidades.NOMBRE+", "+Utilidades.PASS+"from "+Utilidades.TABLA_USUARIO+" where "+Utilidades.NOMBRE+"='"+usr+"' and "+Utilidades.PASS+"='"+pass+"'",null);
```

El query que construira incorrectamente sería:

```
"select nombre, passwordfrom usuario where nombre='...' and password='...'"
```

Te recomiendo realices este cambio, que en realidad anexa espacios para construir correctamente el query:

`fila=db.rawQuery("select "+ Utilidades.NOMBRE+", "+Utilidades.PASS+" from 
 "+Utilidades.TABLA_USUARIO+" where "+Utilidades.NOMBRE+"='"+usr+"' and "+Utilidades.PASS+"='"+pass+"'",null`);